# Async function in for loop works too slow. How can I improve the performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-maps

In the application I am working on I draw a circe with a mouse click on Google Maps. Mouse click sets the center of the circle. The radius of the circle is 0.5 miles. With using [brandannee's node-gtfs](https://github.com/brendannee/node-gtfs), I make async calls to find the routes within the 0.5 mile radius. There are usually multiple routes for each circle. Then I put a marker for the closest bus stop on each route for only one directions (only on southbound or northbound) inside of this circle. The problem is; it works slow. I changed my `findClosestStop` function's time complexity from `n` to `log(n)` hoping it will make a significant difference. It made a difference but still, it takes from 4 to 10 seconds to put all the markers, depends on the number of near by routes.This is the first project I am using NodeJS and AngularJS. And I was familiar only with JavaScript's syntax before this project. I want to know what can I do to make this work faster? Am I making a conceptual mistake? When I wait for the answers, I will move the (finding closest stop) functionality to the back-end side to see if it makes a difference in performance even though I don't think so, since there will be same amount of computation.

Please let me know if you need more information. Looking forward to hear some feedback on this. Thanks in advance.

**controller.js**

```
    ...

        var distance = new distance.Distance();

    ...
        function createGTFSCluster(name, lat, lng, walk, bike, map) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var clusterCenter = new graph.Center(lat, lng, map);
            var cluster = new graph.NodeCluster(clusterCenter, walkRadius, bikeRadius);

            cluster.setName(name);

            getRoutesNearby(cluster.clusterCenter, cluster.bikeRadius)
                .then(function(results) {
                    // Set the cluster's nearby routes
                    var routes = results[0];
                    cluster.nearbyRoutes = routes;
                    angular.forEach(routes, function(route, index){
                        getStopsByRoute(agency_key,route.route_id, 1).then(function(json){
                                            console.log(index, '->', route.route_id);
                            var stops = json[0];
                            var closestStop = distance.getClosestStop(stops, cluster);
                            cluster.setNodes(closestStop, route);
                        })
                    });
                        // Set the cluster's nodes to the stops found
                        deferred.resolve(cluster);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    ...


    // Retrieves the routes near a certain point on the map
        //
        // Input: cluster - A node cluster on the map we are finding routes for
        // Output: A promise whose results are the nearby route IDs
        function getRoutesNearby(center, radius) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Query the GTFS service for nearby routes and draw them
            gtfs.getRoutesByLocation(agency_key, center.lat, center.lon, radius)
                .then(function(json) {
                    //Get all route objects not only IDs
                    var routes = [];
                    for(index in json){
                        routes.push(json[index]);
                    }

                    // We got the routes, resolve
                    deferred.resolve(routes);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
...

    function getStopsByRoute(agency_key, route_id, direction_id){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        gtfs.getStopsByRoute(agency_key, route_id, direction_id)
            .then(function(json){ //all stops on the route in one direction
                var stopsArr =[];
                stopsArr.push(json.data[0].stops);
                deferred.resolve(stopsArr);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
    }
```

**distance.js**

```
    Distance.prototype.getClosestStop = function (stops, cluster){
      var closestStop = findClosestStop(stops, cluster);
      return closestStop;
    }

  function findDistance(stopObj, clusterObj){

    var stopCenter = {
      lat:stopObj.stop_lat,
      lon:stopObj.stop_lon
    };
    var clusterCenter = clusterObj.clusterCenter;

    var lat1 = stopCenter.lat;
    var lat2 = clusterCenter.lat;
    var lon1 = stopCenter.lon;
    var lon2 = clusterCenter.lon;
    var x1 = lat2 - lat1;
    var x2 = lon2 - lon1;
    var dLat = toRadians(x1);
    var dLon = toRadians(x2);
    var R = 3958.756; // miles
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                  Math.cos(toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRadians(lat2)) *
                  Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d;
  }


function toRadians(number){
  var inRadian = number * Math.PI / 180;
//  console.log('number->', number, 'inRadian->', inRadian);
  return inRadian;
}


     function findClosestStop(stops, cluster){
       //set new indeces
      var startIndex = 0;
      var endIndex = stops.length-1;

      //set new stop objects
      var firstStop = stops[startIndex];
      var lastStop = stops[endIndex];
      var closestStop;
      var returnIndex = 0;

      //dS: distance between the first stop and the cluster Center
      //dE: distance between the last stop and the cluster center
      var dS = findDistance(firstStop, cluster);
      var dE = findDistance(lastStop, cluster);
      if (dS > dE){
        startIndex = startIndex+endIndex / 2;
        returnIndex = 1;
      }
      if(dE > dS){
        endIndex = startIndex+endIndex / 2;
        returnIndex = 0;
      }

      if(stops.length > 2){
        stops = stops.slice(startIndex,(endIndex+1));
        return findClosestStop(stops, cluster);
      }else if(stops.length === 2){
        return stops[returnIndex];
      }else{
        return stops[0];
      }
    }
```

Comment: computation on the server side is much faster than client side. Still, I don´t really understand why it takes 4 seconds, what is your n and how big can it be? Also, while findClosestStop does run in log n steps, we don´t know what findDistance is doing

Comment: @juvian, n is the number of bus stops on a route. In my experience n is never more than 105. In an area with 0.5 or 1 mile (max) radius, the maximum number of routes is not more than 10. So it should be 10 * lg(105). I updated the distance.js to include findDistance method. And I could be fine with 4 seconds but it takes longer. I don't understand why it takes this long as well, and that's what I am trying to find out.

Comment: You should try using chrome profiling to check which part is taking long to compute: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: @juvian, thanks for the advice. It took me couple hours to understand how to use developer tools. I finally managed to see my computation takes about 50 ms but the server response takes about 4 seconds in average. I understood why when I looked into the source code. Thanks again!

Comment: great! I have never used it myself, but know it´s a nice tool :). Yeah, something was deeply wrong if 105 * log(105) was taking 4 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

Where are you losing the time?

Id recommend using some

```
console.time(timerName);
```

Too see where you lose the time. If you exactly know where you lose the analysis would be much easier.

105 sets of data should be no problem what so ever for a client side application.

For now I'd recommend running these two snippets in your console

This snippet counts your Angular Digests. Simply put it into your console and then use your application.

```
(function monitorDigestCycle(angular) {
  var injector = angular.element(document.body).injector();
  if (!injector) {
    throw new Error('Missing Angular injector on the document body');
  }
  var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
  function dummy() {
    console.count('digest cycle');
  }
  window.stopWatching = $rootScope.$watch(dummy);
  console.log('run window.stopWatching() to stop watching the digest cycle');
}(window.angular));
```

Or this snippet. It wraps a function (you will need to adjust the snippet for your own use) and records a chrome profiler of the function call. This makes it easy to analyze.

```
(function profileScopeMethod() {
  var selector = 'find';
  var methodName = 'find';
  var name = selector + ':' + methodName;

  /* global angular */
  var el = angular.element(document.getElementById(selector));
  var scope = el.scope() || el.isolateScope();
  console.assert(scope, 'cannot find scope from ' + name);

  var fn = scope[methodName];
  console.assert(typeof fn === 'function', 'missing ' + methodName);
  var $timeout = el.injector().get('$timeout');
  var $q = el.injector().get('$q');

  scope[methodName] = function () {
    console.profile(name);
    console.time(name);

    // method can return a value or a promise
    var returned = fn();
    $q.when(returned).finally(function finishedMethod() {
      console.timeStamp('finished', methodName);

      $timeout(function afterDOMUpdate() {
        console.timeStamp('dom updated after', methodName);
        console.timeEnd(name);
        console.profileEnd();
        scope[methodName] = fn;
        console.log('restored', name);
      }, 0);
    });
  };
  console.log('wrapped', name, 'for measurements');
}());
```

Here you can find even more code snippets to analyze angular applications

```
https://github.com/bahmutov/code-snippets
```

Comment: Robin, thanks a lot for the answer. These are all very new to me and it will take a bit time. I will write back as soon as i have answers to your questions and made some sense of the snippets you sent. I am currently working on understanding how to use Chrome profiles, since I'd never used this tool before.

Comment: Robin, thanks for the suggestions. I finally managed to see -with using chrome developer tools- the performance issue is not in my computation but it's on the server side. I ran the first snippet in the console. It didn't throw any errors. But I don't understand how it was supposed to help me either. I want to make use out of your answer. What should I be looking into to understand these code snippets better?

Comment: The first snippet i posted console logs your angular digest cicles. That beeing said we need to go a little deeper. Every change that you make on the scope issues a digest cicle of the angular core. A good example of this could be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxZE8SqC7as. The second snippet was to wrap an angular function so that once it gets called it starts a chrome profiler and it stoped the profile once the function call is done. This will help you do more in depth analysis of a function. Chromes dev tools also mark "expensive" stuff in javascript  (also explained in video).